# solidity sign with EIP712

Tags: ethereum, solidity

i read smart contract and confused. as the lesson tell us about ABI----

```
The Contract Application Binary Interface (ABI) is the standard way to interact with contracts in the Ethereum ecosystem, both from outside the blockchain and for contract-to-contract interaction.
```

```
 bytes32 public constant DOMAIN_TYPEHASH = keccak256("EIP712Domain(string name,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)");

...

    function delegateBySig(address delegatee, uint nonce, uint expiry, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public {
        bytes32 domainSeparator = keccak256(abi.encode(DOMAIN_TYPEHASH, keccak256(bytes(name)), getChainId(), address(this)));
        bytes32 structHash = keccak256(abi.encode(DELEGATION_TYPEHASH, delegatee, nonce, expiry));
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", domainSeparator, structHash));
        address signatory = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(signatory != address(0), "Comp::delegateBySig: invalid signature");
        require(nonce == nonces[signatory]++, "Comp::delegateBySig: invalid nonce");
        require(now <= expiry, "Comp::delegateBySig: signature expired");
        return _delegate(signatory, delegatee);
    }
```

i was very confused that how ABI can use EIP712Domain?(EIP712Domain not a global varaibles) is EIP712Domain exist method at evm so it can understand ... or exist other contract?

Answer (score 1):

In this context that you've shown, `EIP712Domain` is not a function or a public property. It's also not a Solidity global variable.

It's just part of a string message that is being signed in the `delegateBySig()` function.

---

ABI stands for "application binary interface" and it's a specification that includes [encoding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.encode#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions) arguments (according to the spec). As well as the JSON representing function definitions that you might be familiar with.

So what this function does:

```
string DOMAIN_TYPEHASH = keccak256("EIP712Domain(string name,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)");
abi.encode(DOMAIN_TYPEHASH, keccak256(bytes(name)), getChainId(), address(this))
```

It generates a binary output that would be the same as the transaction data if you were calling the `EIP712Domain()` function with parameters `keccak256(bytes(name))`, `getChainId()` and `address(this)`.

Comment: question is abi.encode use this string which contains EIP712Domain function signature。 ABI is a binary interface。but how it works internel？ real confused

Comment: I see now. Updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: yes。 but it is still strange right？ the first argument of abi.encode at this  is  DOMAIN_TYPEHASH。 if we not see it string type.   it is a function and receive abi.encode other args as param。but at whole files can't found EIP712Domain this function. so where is EIP712Domain defined? EVM how to know has this function?

Comment: This whole snippet doesn't call the `EIP712Domain()` function - it just generates a signature. So the function doesn't have to be implemented. It's enough (for the context of `abi.encode`) that it defines the data types in the 1st argument definition.

Comment: ok really  thanks very much . i will take some time to understand this